# Rにおけるcsvファイル（UTF-8・BOM付き）の読み込みについて

Tags: r

Pythonを用いて、某口コミサイトから口コミ情報をcsvファイルとして取得したのですが、
UTF-8のBOM無しだと文字化けが発生したため、BOM付きで保存を行ないました。

そのcsvファイルをRにインポートしようとしたところ、エラーが発生してしまったため、
ご助言をいただきたいです。

以下、データとコード、表示されるエラー文になります。
また、R・Rstudioに関しては6月下旬頃にインストールし直したため、
バージョンは最新版となっているかと思います。
（データは膨大な量となっているため、一部を抜粋したものになりますが、
こちらも同様のエラーが発生することを確認済みです）

**データ**（データ名：kuchikomi0.csv）

```
リピート
好き！
詳細をみる
```

**コード**

```
kuchikomi <- read.csv("kuchikomi0.csv", header=FALSE, fileEncoding="utf-8-BOM")
```

**表示されるエラー文**

```
file(file, "rt", encoding = fileEncoding) でエラー: 'utf-8-BOM' から '' へのサポートされていない変換です
```

Rを本格的に学習し始めたのは最近のことになりますので、ごく基本的なご質問かもしれません。
また、当方初めての質問となります故、質問文中の記述が足りない等あるかと思います。
その際はご指摘していただければ可能な範囲で対応していきますので、
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 大文字にしたところ無事に実行することができました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純に 小文字の `utf-8-BOM` から 大文字の `UTF-8-BOM` に変えれば動作するようです。

参考

[Read a UTF-8 text file with BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624796/read-a-utf-8-text-file-with-bom)

Answer (score 0):

readr package のread_csv関数を使ってみたらどうでしょうか？

```
library(readr)
kuchikomi <- read.csv("kuchikomi0.csv", header=FALSE)
```